# Java MySQL possible to cause a deadlock?

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, transactions, deadlock

I write a java application where different threads (each thread has an own connection object using a connection pool c3p0) call a method like that.

Pseudo code:

```
void example(Connection connection) {
    connection.update("LOCK TABLES Test WRITE");
    resultSet = connection.query("SELECT * FROM Test WHERE Id = '5'");

    if (resultSet.next()) {
        connection.update("UPDATE Test SET Amount = '10' WHERE Id = '5'");
    } else {
        connection.update("INSERT INTO Test (Id, Amount) VALUES ('5', '10')");
    }

    connection.update("UNLOCK TABLES");
    connection.commit();
}
```

There are a few other similar methods which lock a table, select/update/insert something and then unlock the table. The aim is to prevent race conditions and deadlocks.

Is it possible to cause MySQL deadlocks when I call such a method from different threads? If yes, can you give me an example how that happens (timing of two transactions which cause a deadlock)? I am a noob with deadlocks and I want to get into this.

Edit: Make clear that the connection that should be used in the method is passed from the thread that calls the method.

Edit: Replace READ with WRITE

Comment: I assume that the "update()" and "query()" methods are using the same connection (not acquiring a new one from the pool).

Comment: @slambeth Yes, the thread that calls the method gets the connection object from the pool and passes it to the method. The whole code in the method uses this connection. autoCommit is false.

Comment: @Jas Yes I use InnoDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot here. As there is no complex logic and the code immediately commits after update, there must be always one thread which goes through. Even in more complex scenarios it would probably require highest serialization level (repeatable reads) which I believe MySql does not support.

Answer (score 1):

This would possibly create a deadlock.  Actually I'm not sure if it'll even execute, because you need to acquire a "WRITE" lock, not a "READ".

Comment: You are right, but I think I have to prevent both (READ and WRITE) to prevent race conditions.

Comment: The lock type designation doesn't identify what other sessions can do, it identifies what "you" can do.  "WRITE" is the higher level of lock - it allows you to write, and blocks access completely from other sessions:

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that (edited). Back to my question, is it possible to cause deadlocks with that code?

Comment: As simply as that is written after your edit... I don't believe so - but this is just your psuedo code.  It gets uglier when there is more than one table involved, and/or there are triggers on the updated tables which are attempting updates themselves.

Comment: The MySQL part of that project is as simply as the pseudo code. There are in fact more tables, but they are independently.